# codeigniter 404 not found on assets loading

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I'm stuck on an issue for hours and I can't get rid of it, I'm trying to load my bootstrap files from my asset folder but I got a 404 error.

As you can see my assets folder is in my root folder

[image]

I call it with base_url function in the head:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

And I got this error in my console:

GET http://127.0.0.1/WeBusy/assets/css/bootstrap.css

GET http://127.0.0.1/WeBusy/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)

**EDIT**

I noticed that everything related to files is failing, for example if I autoload the library session, I have this errors:

```
Message: mkdir(): Invalid path
Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Message: Session: Configured save path '' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created.
Filename: C:\Users\User\Dropbox\WeBusy\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have left your base url blank

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Change to

```
WARNING: You MUST set this value!

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/WeBusy/';
```

If you are using CI3 versions must be set

You may need to use index.php

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/assets/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Nope my base url is set `$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/WeBusy/';` and I don't need to use index.php because I have this in my .htaccess: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Instead of the ip address put localhost in `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/WeBusy/';`

Answer (score 0):

Access it like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```